# react-native - yarn install - node-pre-gyp ERR! build error

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm trying to build an app with `yarn install` but it's showing a lot of errors. I have no clue on what is that.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
~/dev/myapp(develop) » ll                                                                                                                                                                          myuser@Leandros-MacBook-Pro
total 712
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  staff   1.4K Jul  4 15:10 App.js
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  staff    12B Sep  5  2018 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  18 myuser  staff   576B Aug 14 09:09 android
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff    65B Jul  4 15:10 android_install.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  staff    55B Aug 14 09:09 app.json
drwxr-xr-x  47 myuser  staff   1.5K Jul  4 15:28 assets
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  staff    76B Jul  4 15:10 babel.config.js
drwxr-xr-x   3 myuser  staff    96B Sep  5  2018 fix-instructions
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  staff   167B Sep  5  2018 index.js
drwxr-xr-x  14 myuser  staff   448B Aug 14 09:09 ios
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  staff   370B Jul  4 15:10 metro.config.js
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  staff   2.6K Aug 14 09:09 package.json
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   104B Jul  4 15:10 release.sh
drwxr-xr-x  11 myuser  staff   352B Sep  5  2018 src
drwxr-xr-x   7 myuser  staff   224B Sep  5  2018 third-party
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  staff   317K Aug 14 09:09 yarn.lock
------------------------------------------------------------
~/dev/myapp(develop) » yarn install                                                                                                                                                                myuser@Leandros-MacBook-Pro
yarn install v1.17.3
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > geofire@4.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "firebase@^2.4.0 || 3.x.x".
warning " > react-native-firebase@4.3.8" has unmet peer dependency "fbjs@*".
warning " > react-native-gesture-handler@1.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-art@>= 16.3.2".
warning " > react-native-gesture-handler@1.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>= 16.3.2".
warning " > react-native-gesture-handler@1.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-web@>= 0.7".
warning " > react-native-maps@0.24.0" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.0 || ^16.0".
warning " > react-native-material-ui@1.30.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native-vector-icons@^4.0.0".
warning "react-navigation > react-navigation-drawer@1.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha".
warning "react-navigation > react-navigation-stack@1.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha".
warning "react-navigation > react-navigation-tabs@1.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha".
warning " > react-number-format@4.0.7" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0".
warning " > styled-components@4.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>= 16.3.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/4] ⠈ fsevents
[-/4] ⠈ waiting...
[-/4] ⠈ waiting...
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.10.3
node-pre-gyp info using node@12.7.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp info check checked for \"/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node\" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@12.7.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@12.7.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.3
gyp info using node@12.7.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.3
gyp info using node@12.7.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info ok
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.3
gyp info using node@12.7.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.3
gyp info using node@12.7.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.10 found at \"/usr/bin/python\"
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.10 found at \"/usr/bin/python\"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info ok
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.3
gyp info using node@12.7.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.3
gyp info using node@12.7.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
../fsevents.cc../fsevents.cc:43:32: error: no template named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
:43:32: error: no template named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
    static void Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports);
                           ~~~~^
    static void Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports);
                           ~~~~^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:89:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone));
          ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:89:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^

  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:90:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagMustScanSubDirs\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagMustScanSubDirs));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:90:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagMustScanSubDirs\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagMustScanSubDirs));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
../src/constants.cc:91  ^:
11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagUserDropped\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagUserDropped));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:91:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagUserDropped\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagUserDropped));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:92:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagKernelDropped\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagKernelDropped));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:92:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagKernelDropped\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagKernelDropped));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:93:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagEventIdsWrapped\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagEventIdsWrapped));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
:  ^93:11: warning:
'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagEventIdsWrapped\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagEventIdsWrapped));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:94:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagHistoryDone\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagHistoryDone));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:94:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagHistoryDone\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagHistoryDone));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
In file included from   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:95:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagRootChanged\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagRootChanged));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:95:11: warning:   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagRootChanged\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagRootChanged));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
:  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
102:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemModified\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemModified));
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:104:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          ^
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemChangeOwner\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemChangeOwner));/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here

  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:103:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemFinderInfoMod\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemFinderInfoMod));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:105:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemXattrMod\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemXattrMod));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
:104:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemChangeOwner\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemChangeOwner));
          ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3365:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
../fsevents.cc:76:16: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
               ^
../fsevents.cc:76:16: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
               ^
../fsevents.cc:76:31: error: no member named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                          ~~~~^
../fsevents.cc../fsevents.cc:76:31: error: no member named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
:void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                          ~~~~^
../fsevents.cc:76:48: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~^
76:48: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~^
../fsevents.cc:76:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'exports'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                                 ^
../fsevents.cc:76:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'exports'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                                 ^
../fsevents.cc../fsevents.cc:76:58: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                                         ^
                                                         ;
:76:58: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                                         ^
                                                         ;
20 warnings and 6 errors generated20 warnings and 6 errors generated.
.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:196:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/bin/node\" \"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"build\" \"--fallback-to-build\" \"--module=/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node\" \"--module_name=fse\" \"--module_path=/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64\" \"--napi_version=4\" \"--node_abi_napi=napi\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:196:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/bin/node\" \"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"build\" \"--fallback-to-build\" \"--module=/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node\" \"--module_name=fse\" \"--module_path=/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64\" \"--napi_version=4\" \"--node_abi_napi=napi\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/bin/node\" \"/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp\" \"install\" \"--fallback-to-build\"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/myuser/dev/myapp/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
✨  Done in 118.80s.
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Additional information:

```
node -v: v12.7.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.7
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: Why do you run install to create an app?

Comment: @hongdevelop I'm running `yarn install` to build this app.. that's the correct way, not?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run '`yarn install`' to build an application. This is the command you will use to install the required module later, run when you are asked to use that command, or delete and reset the '`node_modules`' file.

1. `npm -g install react-native-cli`
2. `react-native init yourproject`
3. `cd yourproject`
4. `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`

Comment: This remark doesn't answer the problem that's been exposed above.

Comment: @morphet81 Read the question carefully and see the code the questioner attempted.